# ActivityViewController very occasionally not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In an app with a large number of users, a tiny percentage are seeing a problem where the activity view for sharing videos doesn't appear at all (no error or hang, just nothing happens). Users with this problem tend to have it consistently, until they do something seemingly unconnected like update to the latest version of iOS (even though the same issue has been seen in the latest version of iOS as well). I've never been able to reproduce the issue, so not sure how to debug.

Is there any reason at all in the following code that the activity view might not appear?

```
func main(closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        closure()
    }
}

...

let objectsToShare = [videoUrl]

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.setValue("Video", forKey: "subject")

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
    UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension"),
    UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"),
    UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
    UIActivityType.assignToContact,
    UIActivityType.openInIBooks,
    UIActivityType.print
]

main {

    activityViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = masterViewController.view
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = self.shareImage.convert(self.shareImage.bounds, to: masterViewController.view)

    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activityType, _, _, _ in
        //share success
    }

    masterViewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)

}
```

Comment: Well, since I commented on one question today with this - why are **you** coding for success? Does it fail with any error? I usually do a `vc.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activity, success, items, error) in self.dismissMe()}` where vc is the controller and `dismissMe() `is a simple function to dismiss `vc`. Your code only, by comment,  "share success".

Comment: good point! I'll check for errors and show a dialog to the user, but i wonder if this particular problem doesn't even reach that point

Comment: I ws actually asking if *you* found anything with that. You may have found something to file with Apple, but this might help you find out something else. (I honestly don't know. Slow network connection, images too large, main thread blocked.... One might hope this could give you some details.)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. No, unfortunately no clues there! Everything totally fine whenever i test it (with error checking in too), on all devices etc.

Comment: The only other thought I have is with the `info.plist` privacy settings. If I recall correctly, once a user says "no" to the popup odd behaviors happen. It sounds like you have some contact with a user (or two) with this issue. Do you know if uninstalling/reinstalling - and the granting access on the popup - resolves the issue?

Comment: good idea, i'll try to find out with the next user that reports it...